# Как открыть 2 потока считывания с консоли или же переоткрыть закрытый поток?

Tags: java

Есть у меня пара статических методов, с считыванием с консоли.
В мейне запускаю оба последовательно.
Ввел данные в одном, закрыл поток. Второй метод тут же вываливается с `IOException`.

Конечно можно вынести `BufferedReader` в поле класса и не закрывать поток, но меня интересует, можно ли как-то без этого обойтись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться классом Console для получения данных от пользователя

```
 Console cons;
 char[] passwd;
 if ((cons = System.console()) != null &&
      (passwd = cons.readPassword("[%s]", "Password:")) != null) {
      ...
      java.util.Arrays.fill(passwd, ' ');
 }
```

`System.console()` всегда возвращает один и тот же объект. `cons.reader()` вернет вам `Reader` и вы можете его закрыть - это не повлияет на его работу.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, уже разобрался.

Comment: @Haart Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Точно, спасибо. Не обратил внимания что галочка есть.